# Looking for a way to configure the RDP-TCP Properties in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

[image]

Is there a way to setup the session for RDP-Tcp proerties in powershell.

Comment: How do you get to that dialog box? Windows version/edition?

Comment: Yes you can
[Microsoft Blog] https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2009/01/09/managing-remote-desktop-services-aka-terminal-services-using-windows-powershell/

Comment: Any reason you're not configuring these settings using a GPO?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RemoteDesktopServices Powershell Module:

```
Import-Module RemoteDesktopServices
```

Then to Set Disconnected Session, Active Session, Idle Session Limits to one Hour use:

```
 Set-Item `
-Path 'RDS:\RDSConfiguration\Connections\Default RDP\SessionTimeLimitSettings\TimeLimitPolicy' `
-Value 0 `
-IdleSessionLimit 3600000 `
-ActiveSessionLimit 3600000 `
-DisconnectedSessionLimit 3600000
```

Browse the RDS Provider to see all the options:

```
Get-ChildItem RDS:
```

- 'Default RDP' in the example is my RDP Connection name, so change it to RDP-Tcp or whatever is your connection name: